# When is the best time to call webview.clearData

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app

I want to add multiple social accounts into my chrome app. To add one account I use webview / listen to "loadcommit" event (unfortunately I can't use chrome.identity). But if user wants to add another account, cookies prevent doing this and token is updated instead.

So I decided to clear cookies before opening auth webview. But if I do this before assigning "src" to webview, callback of webview.clearDara() doesn't fire. So when is the best time to run this method?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to load blank page from social network domain and call clearData after "loadcommit" happens. And after 0.1s redirect to login page.